# how would be possbile to assign a value from a rout call to a terraform variable?

Tags: terraform

is it possible to get a value from a data call and assign it to a variable ?

i m trying to get some values with the calls like :

```
    data "oci_core_vcns" "test_vcns" {
    #Required
        compartment_id = "${var.compartment_ocid}"

    }


    output "vcn_state" {
      value =  ${data.oci_core_vcns.test_vcns.virtual_networks[0].state}"
   }
```

i dont want to reference to my scripts the return value

```
   ${data.oci_core_vcns.test_vcns.virtual_networks[0].state}
```

but i wanted to do something like

```
 var.vcn_state = {data.oci_core_vcns.test_vcns.virtual_networks[0].state}
```

where vcn_state is declared as a variable in my variables.tf file 
but this code is not working

Would be possible to create a variable like :

```
variable "vcn_state" {
  type        = "string"
  default     = ""
}
```

and then assign to it values from data calls ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

*Input Variables* in Terraform are most analogous to the parameters on a function: they are assigned by the caller and *used* by the module configuration.

What you are looking for here is an analog to *local variables*, which in Terraform are called [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html), reflecting the fact that they have a fixed expression at declaration time and cannot vary during an operation or between operations.

```
variable "compartment_ocid" {
  type = string
}

data "oci_core_vcns" "test_vcns" {
  compartment_id = var.compartment_ocid
}

locals {
  vcn_state = data.oci_core_vcns.test_vcns.virtual_networks[0].state 
}

output "vcn_state" {
  value =  local.vcn_state
}
```

To complete the analogy to functions, note that *output values* (the `output` block type) serve as similar role as a function's return values.

---

The above example uses Terraform 0.12 syntax. If you are using Terraform 0.11 then the above patterns should work if you wrap each of the reference expressions in the `"${ ... }"` interpolation syntax.